# Fixing a door hinge when the part of the board it was attached to is gone?

Tags: doors, basement

In a house built in 1950 there is a door in the basement that the top hinge is connected but the bottom hinge is not attached because the part of the board it was attached to is gone.  I do not know what is holding the rest of the board in place, nor do I know what happened to the bottom part of the board.

I also don’t know how to fix it.  Here are the photos of it:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The wood next to the stone wall rotted.**

You have a stone foundation.  Those are never perfectly sealed.  Moisture got thru and rotted the piece of wood next to the stone.  Maybe moisture came thru the wall or maybe up thru the ground.

Remove the door and set it aside.  Now you will be looking at the rotten piece of wood attached to the stone wall.  Get rid of it.  If you want a set up like you had, put a new piece there that is the same size.  When you get the old piece out you will see how it was attached to the stone.  Maybe there will be some holes in the stone you can use for the new piece.  Then put the door back where it was and attach the hinges to the new piece of wood.

It occurs to me that this would be a fine job for that fake plastic wood which will fill the space and receive the hinge from the door, but not rot.  Or at least use some wood full of preservatives!

Comment: Yes, pressure treated lumber would be perfect for this, as would composite (wood & plastic) "wood". Fully plastic (all PVC) is used for trim and _seems_ idea, however, I don't think it has the strength to be used for structural purposes like this - there's a reason it comes in 1x sizes (for trim work) and not 2x sizes (for structural work).